# xpath taking a list item following a specific h4 text

Tags: xpath

From the following XML-document, I'm trying to specify XPath that will capture the text that immediately follows the h4-headline "Source", namely - in this example - "Information about the source":

```
    <div class="doc-inf doc-inf-information">
      <h3>Document information</h3>
      <div>
          <h4>Source</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Information about the source</li>
          </ul>
```

I've tried the following:

```
//h4[contains(text(), "Source")]/ul/li'
```

Which doesn't seem to work. Would anyone be able to help? I would greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT:**

My problem (which I didn't specify fully, sorry) is that this div tag has multiple h4 tags in it of which I want to select the ul-child for each:

```
    <div class="doc-inf doc-inf-information">
      <h3>Document information</h3>
      <div>
          <h4>Source</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Source information</li>
          </ul>
        
          <h4>Language</h4>
          <ul>
                          <li><a href="/search-results/1/%7B%22language%22%3A%22chi%22%7D">Swedish</a></li>
                    </ul>
        
          <h4>Publishers</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/search- results/1/%7B%22publisher%22%3A%221%22%7D">Publishing Project</a></li>
                    </ul>
        
        <h4>Record ID</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>36785</li>
        </ul>
```

In essence, I'm trying to grab the child under h4 headlines "Source", "Language", "Publishers", "Record ID" (**= what I'm interested in is "Source information", "Swedish", "Publishing Project" and "36785"**) but the h4 headlines are inconsistently placed across pages so I need to be able to target the children of the specific headlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly accessing the tag `<h4>`, which has no children, therefore the following doesn't work:

```
//h4[contains(text(), "Source")]/ul/li
```

Try this instead:

```
//div[h4[contains(text(), "Source")]]/ul/li/text()
```

which searches for a `<div>` that has the tag `<h4>` in it with the text 'Source' and then it selects the `<ul>` child.

Comment: This leads me down the right path and makes sense. Thank you. However, when I then try to grab e.g. "Record ID" by modifying your xpath example, it doesn't work - is there a better way to solve this problem? I've edited my original post to reflect this question. Thank you for your time and sorry to add an extra question.

Comment: //h4[text()="Source" or text()="Record ID" ]/following-sibling::*[1]/li/text()  |  //h4[text()="Language" or text()="Publishers" ]/following-sibling::*[1]/li/a/text()     hope this helps.